# Allow { and } in a URL validation regular expression

Tags: regex

I have this regular expression for URL validation:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

And I need to allow users to use custom tags in the URL for example {user_name} (Later I will remplace user_name with a valid value)

So, what I need is to allow URLs like:

```
http://www.google.com/search?&oq={user_name}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just escape them `\{.+\}` with backslash

Comment: Thanks Dynamic, where should I add \{.+\}?